# CSOM Powershell Remove List from List Collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

On Sharepoint Online, using a Powershell/CSOM console app, in a Site Collection with 34 DocLibs, I need to extract a listing of DocLib Items and their attributes.

I want to allow the user to specify either 'All' DocLibs, or a specific DocLib using a Program Code (i.e. 'LCL', for 'LCL Library').

My Question: How do I loop through all Lists in a ListCollection if the user enters 'All', but 'loop' through only the LCL Library if the user enters 'LCL'?

One idea I had was to remove the 'extra' Lists from the ListCollection when a single DocLib is entered, which it looks something like this:

```
$lists = $web.Lists

if ($libCode -ne "All") 
{ 
    foreach($list in $lists)
    {
        if($list.Title -ne $libName)
        { $lists.RemoveChild($list) }
    }
}

foreach ($list in $lists)
{

    $context.Load($list)
    $context.Load($list.RootFolder.Folders)
    $context.ExecuteQuery();

    ...

}
```

This approach errors with the following:

> Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List] does not contain a 
>   method named 'RemoveChild'.At C:\Users\thebear\Desktop\SEDA\SEDAGetItemData.ps1:46 
>   char:11
>   +         { $lists.RemoveChild($list) }

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Duh...

I moved the filter inside the foreach loop to process only the specified DocLib, like so:

```
$lists = $web.Lists

foreach ($list in $lists)
{
    if (($libCode -ne "All") -and ($list.Title -ne $libName)) { continue }

    $context.Load($list)
    $context.Load($list.RootFolder.Folders)
    $context.ExecuteQuery();

    ...
}
```